# Windows 10 Stuck in a Recovery Mode Boot Loop

Tags: windows, boot

##### Problem

A friend asked me to repair his wife's computer, which "wouldn't boot".
The computer is stuck in the infamous Windows boot loop, where it will just boot to Recovery Mode over and over again. None of the typical options work, none of the advanced options work.

##### What I've tried

1. Restarting, obviously.
2. Startup repair -> no dice.
3. System image recovery -> there was no image.
4. Rolling back the Windows update. -> This failed.
5. In the RE cmd, I checked out the disks and partitions.

The `C:\` partition, which contains the Windows installation, was completely full. So freed up some space by removing old installer files in her Downloads folder. This did not solve the problem.

Running `chkdsk /f` `DISM` and `sfc scannow` all failed. `chkdsk` was unable to produce a log file.

`sfc` produced a logfile, indicating that there was an issue with the service stack, namely `wcp.dll` is missing. I found it at the path indicated, but I'm guessing this file is corrupted.

And `DISM` spit out several different errors, including a `1009` configuration registry database is corrupted.

`Bootrec` can't find any windows installations. Not surprising, since the files are likely corrupted.

##### What now?

I've spent *hours* on her computer and have not come any closer to solving this. I feel like I've exhausted every route I could find.

Is re-installing Windows via USB my only option?

Will her data be preserved? Or will I be able to pull data off of her computer?

Comment: Does it offer you to boot into safe mode(under troubleshoot->Startup Settings, should be 4th option)? https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/85d63652-68b6-9a70-60e4-c63825eaca59.png

Comment: It offers it, but that fails. I'm making an iso today. I had to go out and buy extra USB sticks, because she only has USB-C and I only have USB-A sticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make a full drive image, using a bootable USB, with tools such as [Macrium Rescue Environment](https://blog.macrium.com/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/browse/search/?q=macrium%20reflect).
- Download the [ISO from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d) to USB using their media creation tool.
- Reinstall, **keeping files**.
- If any files were lost or damaged, recover them from the image.

Actually, this might be faster than SFC/DISM, which you already tried.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had to go out to get USB sticks that actually fit her computer, since there are only USB-C ports and I don't have any USB-C sticks laying around.

Comment: This also didn't work. I made the image of the drive using Macrium and verified that it worked, but I can't actually access her files in her home folder when I browse them on my PC.
Windows also does not allow me to reinstall while keeping the files.

Comment: @LittleLulatsch, when browsing folders in Macrium Reflect, check, "**Enable access to restricted folders**".  As for why you cannot reinstall Windows, provide more data.

Comment: Thanks, for the tip with Macrium. Regarding Windows, the first option to "upgrade" Windows isn't available only clean install. Or is there an option later to keep the files?

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/reinstall-windows-d8369486-3e33-7d9c-dccc-859e2b022fc7 for explanation of all options. *Before* reinstalling, though, **if you've made a full drive image**, then you should be able to recover data, at the least, after reinstallation, even if files do get deleted.

Comment: As of right now there are no ways to keep files and reinstall Windows 10, when booting from installation medium. I ended up doing a clean install and am working on getting the drivers installed and updating. Thanks for your help and for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

Try running Repair with the Microsoft Windows 10 USB.

[Microsoft Media Creation Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

I am not sure (depending on where stuck) whether this will work, but most likely not. However, you can always try. If the repair runs, use the Keep Data option.

If the repair does not work (more likely here), boot with a Bootable USB Key, recover what data you can.

Now boot with the Manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App and test hardware.  The main disk may have a problem.

Once hardware issue are resolved, and data is secure, reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I'll start with the Windows USB.

I'm not completely sure what you mean by "manufacturer's hardware diagnostics"-- the manufacturer is Huawei and I can't find any information about diagnostic mode for their laptops.

Comment: Try a good disk test App to check the drive. You will need a bootable USB for such a test app.  It may be worthwhile just to try a new disk.